# How to extract a string between two static key?

Tags: regex, linux

In a string as following:

```
alias LXX "|lp -dYYYYYYY -o nb -o raw -s 2>/dev/null",
```

*`lp -d[YYYYYY] -o`* can happen in the part of the string. [LXX] and  [YYYYYY] are the parts that need to be extracted from each line.

Any solution using regex will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: could you please format that log and add a desired output so others can see and able to help  you.

Comment: I hope this way makes it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux you can use grep with -o and -P to do that:

```
grep -oP 'lp -d\K\S*' filename.txt
```

Comment: Saboteur, your bash command works for the most part but it ignored several lines e.g. alias L30 "|lp -dl30 -o   and alias L31 "|lp -dl31 -o nb and ....  Any idea? should I change the regex ?

Comment: you should provide example of types in the question. May be you have multiple spaces between lp and -dl in the ingored line. Can't guess, need to check with real examples.

Answer (score 1):

grep with look-around :

```
grep -Po '(?<=lp -d).*?(?= -o)' filename.txt
```